# rails asset pipeline javascript "SyntaxError: Unexpected token export"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku

I've got the lovely topojson library working for me in a Rails app locally:

https://github.com/topojson/topojson

and it's allowing us to show some nice geoJSON in a google map like so:

[image: dev machine in production mode - all good]

I show it with the map.js file exposed, since that seems to be where the trouble is when we deploy to heroku.  On heroku the map.js file gives an error on chrome:

> maps-....js:27 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

and a similar error (although on a different line) on firefox:

> SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module maps-...js:1

[image: syntax error involving export when same system is deployed on heroku]

I've been in touch with heroku support who suggested locking down our npm version, as it seems like the minified js file is ending up with slightly different content locally than on heroku.  I note that I've done everything I can to replicate production mode locally, clobbering and recompiling the static assets etc. and running like so:

```
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true DEVISE_SECRET_KEY=1234 AIRBRAKE_PROJECT_ID=1234 RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails s
```

but try as I might I cannot replicate the issue on my dev machine.

You can see all the gory details in this PR https://github.com/AgileVentures/LocalSupport/pull/1069  and I was wondering if anyone had any ideas about anything else that could be a difference between my dev machine and heroku that could be leading to the javascript files compiling differently?  On heroku we have the following:

```
export*from"topojson-client";export*from"topojson-server";export*from"topojson-simplify
```

but there is no mention of the offending `export` keywords in the static assets compiled locally, but there they are in the files on the heroku server.   I've been trying all sort of methods to ensure that I'm deleting cached files and that that the changes I am making are being reflected both locally and on heroku.

I've also been investigating ways to try and handle the export keyword (new in es6) but that seems like an even deeper rabbit hole, i.e. sprockets 4 or webpack or similar.

Anyhow, if anyone has any thoughts on other things that could cause heroku to be operating differently here I'd love to hear them, so I can either lock them down or work out how to replicate the bug locally.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: great suggestion from heroku to try NODE_ENV=production locally to see if I could replicate the issue on my dev machine, but that didn't seem to make any impact ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku support are saying that the problem here is using npm with the asset pipeline and the better approach would be to use webpacker